# I am using __android_log_print and not able to print the log messages on logcat

Tags: java, android

**This is the .cpp file and the code is**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_compute_MainActivity_AddNumbers(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint v1, jint v2)
{
_android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "VaxVoIP", "The value of 1 + 1 is %d", 1+1);

         return -1;

    //return (v1 + v2);
}
```

**This is the Android.mk file**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
```

**Here we give our module name and source file(s)**

```
LOCAL_MODULE    := add
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := add.cpp\
                   add.h\

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And the other error that I'm trying to solve is while making the .so file

```
_android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "VaxVoIP", "The value of 1 + 1 is %d", 1+1);
was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 1):

John is right about it. I just got it resolved by including `#include <android/log.h>`and also add **LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl -landroid** in android.mk file

Answer (score 0):

If that's the whole .cpp file, you're going to need to #include something that defines _android_log_print.

Comment: Is it possible to print jstring?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include

```
#include <android/log.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the buffer. Put `\n` at the end of the string.

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "VaxVoIP", "The value of 1 + 1 is %d\n", 1+1);
```

Also don't forget to put double underscores rather than one single underscore.

Comment: The doc specifically says that __android_log_print handles this: "Note that a newline character ("\n") will be appended automatically to your log message, if not already there." https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/log_8h.html#a18922cb70c6c2064250de96451c99eed